# Send Email Alerts Using Google Cloud Data Fusion

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I am trying to send out alert emails after each run in data fusion using the Email plugin in Data Fusion.

However, I always get errors for authentication, I am not sure how to set it up using my gamil account, could you please help me with it.

Also, I am wondering if it is possible to send the alert email using the service account that was used to run the pipeline (proejctid-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com)

Here are the setting I have tried, I guess it's something wrong with my settings but I am not able to find it:

Sender: my-email-address@gmail.com
User Name: my-email-address@gmail.com
Password: the password to my email address
Protocol: I have tried smtp and smtps, not working
Host: smtp.gmail.com
Port: I have tried both 465 and 587, not working

Thank you so much for your help!

Best regards,
Yuan